Joining CloudWatchLog Insights
I am trying to create basic dashboards of Step function logs with CloudWatchLogInsights.
Here is the query that I am sending
fields @timestamp, @logStream, details.error, details.cause
| filter type = 'ExecutionFailed'
| limit 100

I also want to retrieve some information(contex_id) from "ExecutionStarted" and add new column in my dashboard. I need to perform a join of type "ExecutionFailed" to type "ExecutionStarted" on "execution_arn" using actual SQL query syntax. Is it possible with cloudwatch log insights
Here are the logs I send query to

I checked the Doc and I see there is no SQL support and join is not possible in Cloudwatch Log insights. But I am wondering how this basic needs could be solved?
